# Nginx: Unknown log format error

Tags: nginx, logging, proxypass, udp

I have a proxy set up that is taking UDP traffic to load balance internal DNS. It is routing the traffic properly to my backend DNS servers, but I cannot seem to get the log formatting to work correctly.

The error I'm receiving is:

`nginx[32103]: nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "dns" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:23`

I have the log format in the http block, and define it in the `stream-->server` block. I tried to set the log_format within the `stream-->server` block, but none of the variables would work.

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
    
    events {
            worker_connections 768;
            # multi_accept on;
    }
    stream {
    
      upstream dns_servers {
        least_conn;
        server 192.168.3.222:53 fail_timeout=10s;
        server 192.168.70.80:53 fail_timeout=10s;
        server 192.168.70.81:53 fail_timeout=10s;
      }
      server { 
        listen 53 udp;
        proxy_pass dns_servers;
        proxy_responses 1;
        proxy_timeout 1s;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log dns;
    
      }
    }
    
    http {
    
            sendfile on;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on;
            keepalive_timeout 65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;
    
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type application/octet-stream;
    
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; 
    
            log_format dns '[$time_local] | $remote_addr | $remote_user | $server_name $host to: $upstream_addr | '
                               '"$request" | $status | upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec '
                               '$msec | request_time $request_time';
    
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log dns;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

I tried to place `log_format` in the stream block, but I start getting `unknown <variable name> variable`.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}
stream {
 log_format dns '[$time_local] | $remote_addr | $remote_user | $server_name $host to: $upstream_addr | '
                           '"$request" | $status | upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec '
                           '$msec | request_time $request_time';

  upstream dns_servers {
    least_conn;
    server 192.168.3.222:53 fail_timeout=10s;
    server 192.168.70.80:53 fail_timeout=10s;
    server 192.168.70.81:53 fail_timeout=10s;
  }
  server { 
    listen 53 udp;
    proxy_pass dns_servers;
    proxy_responses 1;
    proxy_timeout 1s;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log dns;

  }
}
```

This will not be a web server at all. It will only serve as a proxy for DNS traffic. How do I properly get the logging to function correctly? This is a default nginx.conf file except for the stream block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `log_format` for use by `stream` `server`s must be declared in the `stream` block, rather than the `http` block. These directives are independent of each other. See the [documentation for the `stream` `log_format`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.html#log_format).

Comment: That is in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce I thought it needed to be emphasized that there are two different `log_format` directives, as this confuses lots of people.

Comment: I read that in a hurry. My bad. Great point! Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer, since you provided the documentation showing how they were independent.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I found the correct variables, and placed everything in my `stream` block according to [this tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-udp-load-balancing-nginx-tips-tricks/).

This is my new `stream` block:

```
stream {

    log_format dns '$remote_addr - - [$time_local] $protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time "$upstream_addr"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log dns;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  
  upstream dns_servers {
    least_conn;
    server 192.168.3.222:53 fail_timeout=10s;
    server 192.168.70.80:53 fail_timeout=10s;
    server 192.168.70.81:53 fail_timeout=10s;
  }
  server { 
    listen 53 udp;
    proxy_pass dns_servers;
    proxy_responses 1;
    proxy_timeout 1s;
  }
}
```

And you can see that it is indeed logging:

```
192.168.2.47 - - [11/Nov/2020:15:29:34 +0000] UDP 200 97 33 0.018 "192.168.3.222:53"
192.168.2.47 - - [11/Nov/2020:15:29:34 +0000] UDP 200 53 37 0.031 "192.168.70.80:53"
192.168.2.47 - - [11/Nov/2020:15:29:34 +0000] UDP 200 142 42 0.046 "192.168.3.222:53"
192.168.2.47 - - [11/Nov/2020:15:29:34 +0000] UDP 200 62 46 0.030 "192.168.70.80:53"
192.168.2.47 - - [11/Nov/2020:15:29:34 +0000] UDP 200 142 38 0.039 "192.168.70.81:53"
```